# Why isn't my wrapper div clearing correctly?

Tags: html, css

My wrapper div is acting like the children divs aren't cleared properly. It's only wrapping a portion of the vertical height of the children divs. Can anyone explain why this is happening? I cleared both of the divs contained by the wrapper.

[packardcarbs.myshopify.com](http://packardcarbs.myshopify.com)

The password is "ataska."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not specify a height for your #content. Remove `height: 100%;` on line 88